# Is it bad software architecture in C++ to create a wrapper class instead of designing from scratch?

Tags: c++, boost, game-engine, software-design, codebase

I'm creating a 3D game  engine on my own using OpenGL and the C++ (with the Boost Libraries).  I guess it goes without saying that it is a *LOT* of work. To lighten the load, I have started to create wrapper classes for things in Boost that closely match my needs, instead of making the same classes from scratch. Also my naming scheme is very different from Boost and the STL so I felt at first that this kept things consistent throughout the codebase.

I am concerned that this practice is bad design technique. Is it OK to do that? What unforseen problems can arise, if any, from creating so many wrapper classes?

Comment: "What unforseen problems can arise" not many really. So long as you properly hide unwanted functionality that doesn't make sense with your wrapper class and you're not super tight on memory then wrapping pre made type s is probably fine.

Comment: Beats the hell out of an inheritance kludge that just changes the names. Downsides are an extra layer of abstraction (that can be transformed into an upside if abstracted correctly) and the possibility of injecting bugs in the wrapper (compared to writing everything from scratch this should be much LESS buggy).

Comment: I just don't much like the idea of writing all my containers, strings, streams, et cetera by hand.

Comment: What value/functionality do your wrapper classes add? Any code you write will need to be documented, tested and maintained. Since you mention "so many wrapper classes", I'm not sure I see how this is "lightening the load".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope it is completely harmless to use wrappers in most cases.

Usually your compiler shall unwind all the function calls and optimize out overhead of sourced libraries.

The slight problem would however be, if you use precompiled binaries, which would introduce some overhead.

To use wrappers in your case (meaning to keep your style convention, slight functionality changes, etc.) is completely OK practice.

***ADD***: Some of the "unforseen" stuff might be extra compile time, mess inside the code (U need to keep using those wrappers consistently...), or some extra functionality or behavior of the original class, that your wrapper does not support.

Comment: Will accept in a few minutes. i just upvoted, have to wait.